# Tree width and clique width of regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, trees, lower-bounds, regular-graph

Consider a $k$ regular graph of $n$ vertices, where $3 \leq k \leq (n-1)$. Is there any upper or lower bound, in the worst case, known for either the tree-width or the clique width of each $k$ regular family?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $k$-regular family, the treewidth and cliquewidth can be both $\Theta(n)$, due to the existence of expanders.

By [On Balanced Separators, Treewidth, and Cycle Rank](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1344) Thm. 2.1, $tw(G) \geq \tilde s(G) -1$, and by the definition of the strict balanced separator number, $\tilde s(G)$ is at least the size of a balanced separator of a graph. A random regular graph is an expander, which in turn makes the size of balanced separators $\Theta(n)$. Thus $tw(G)=\Theta(n)$.

By [The Tree-Width of Clique-Width Bounded Graphs without $K_{n,n}$](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-40064-8_19), every graph of clique-width $k$ which does not
contain the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ for some $n > 1$ as a subgraph has tree-width at most $3k(n − 1) − 1$. It's possible to take $n=3$ for random regular graphs, thus the clique-width is also $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: Is there a reference to the fact that no random regular graph has $K_{3 \times 3}$ as a subgraph? Also, for what regularity does this fact break down? It is obviously false for a complete ($n-1$ regular graph), because the tree width of a complete graph is linear, but the clique width is bounded. It is also false for $n-2$ and $n-3$ regular graphs for a similar reason. Is it true from $n-4$ regular graphs?

Comment: @RandomMatrices It's true for n-4 regular graphs. As the complement of an (n-4)-regular graph is a cubic graph, and the complement graph of a graph of clique-width k has clique-width at most 2k, the (n-4)-regular graph has clique-width Θ(n) if the cubic graph is taken to be a random cubic graph.

Comment: The reference for $K_{3,3}$ is N. C. Wormald's survey, Models of random regular graphs, Lemma 2.7. The lemma states that for fixed d and fixed graph F with more edges than vertices, almost all random d-regular graphs do not contain F as a subgraph.